# Terminating previous tags in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, tags

I'm pulling some text passages from a database that have some minimal formatting using simple `<p>`, `<div>`, and `<br>` tags (stored right in the text--I wish it were different, but it's a legacy system).  These are all previously created passages, and they often have mistakes, including missing some closing tags for the `<p>` and `<div>` tags.

Obviously, when I insert the passage into a page and it has missing closing tags, it makes some things go willy-nilly.

I'm using ASP like the following:

```
<%  asp code to get the text from the database%>
<div id="passageGoesHere">
    <%=passageText%>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is fool-proof the containing div to not let unterminated tags mess up the rest of my page.  Any ideas would be appreciated, in html, css, javascript, or ASP.

Comment: Unclosed `<p>` tags are not a problem if you're wrapping the whole thing in a `<div>`.

Comment: Test the output with comparison operators and if the closing tag doesn't exist in the string, append it. You will also need to parse what the starting tag is to determine the tag to append.

Comment: Classic ASP.  And `<p>` tags aren't much of a problem alone, but they seem to make things look a bit more confangled when there is also an unclosed `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of HTML Tidy for Classic ASP

http://vsbabu.org/techbits/tidywithasp.html

Comment: Of course!  Seems kind of silly not having thought of this before...  I was just looking for some magical tag that would terminate all previous tags or something, which of course doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

An absent end tag is not necessarily a mistake. Depending on the actual element, the end tag may be required, optional, or even disallowed. Except if it's really XHTML instead of HTML.

So if it's true that "things go willy-nilly", you need to first find out why exactly.

Comment: Well, the html was created using a subpar javascript wysiwyg that simply didn't close the `<div>` tags sometimes.  Nothing complicated.  When trying to apply CSS to the div containing the passage, that throws a wrench in things.